# How can I generalize the equation in order to find the determinant for given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, self-learning

I have a question related to  [my previous past](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559630/finding-eigenvalues-for-given-matrices). This is just information question.

I have this matrix. [image]

For example, assume that N =4, then I can find eigenvalues with this following equation

$$(2*4 - \lambda)^4 - 4^4=0$$

So in general, for any N, I can find eigenvalues with this following equation

$$(2*N - \lambda)^N - N^N=0$$

(this equation is indeed the determinant of $D_N-\lambda*I$.

Is this equation true to find the determinant of $D_N-\lambda*I$?

Comment: Every question is an information question

Comment: No, the second formula does not necessarily hold as a consequence of the first

Comment: Well, where is my mistake in the second equation? how can modify / re-write this  Second equation? Please give you a suggestion or correction? Many thanks @Omnomnomnom

Comment: the mistake is that you're saying "because of [formula for $\det(D_4 - \lambda)$], we can conclude [formula for $\det(D_N - \lambda)$]". That is an inherently wrong line of reasoning.

Comment: Well, I understand what you said.  How can I write the general determinant for given matrix $D_N$ ? At this point, can you help me? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: I know how to find eigenvalues basically. But this is too complex. I cannot handle it dear @Omnomnomnom

Comment: You have not included the original statement of the question in either of your posts.  What is the exact question that is being asked or task being requested?  If the only task is "examine the eigenvalues", then why are you trying to find a formula for the determinant of $D_N$?

Comment: If you are particularly interested in finding and proving such a formula, you could apply the general formula given on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: Okay, I say more clearly. I am sorry for that.  I only want to find the Eigenvalues of this matrix each for N=4, 8, 16... etc. In the Matlab.  So I need to form a general equation to find its eigenvalues in Matlab. (Toolbox functions are not accepted. ) @Omnomnomnom

Comment: If you're meant to use Matlab, then presumably you should be using one of the [built-in functions like eig](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html). This would not typically be referred to as a "toolbox function".

Comment: Thank you so much. In fact, you help very much. My last question is that how can write this my circulant matrix? I searched for circulant matrix matlab code. I found it. But I get error. Can you write its code? thank you again so much dear @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it seems that what is really needed is code that will produce the eigenvalues of the matrix $D_N$.  We can produce this outcome with the following script:

```
N = 2^3;
D = circshift(eye(N),-1) + circshift(eye(N),1) - 2*eye(N);
eig(D)
```

Comment: You are the best!! Thanks a lot :))